# Problema ao exibir um json capturado de uma API em meu widget de coluna - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tenho um problema que não consegui resolver, então vou até você para me dar uma mão. Estou buscando um json de uma API, o processo de busca de dados vai bem (eu uso uma **print()** que me mostra que se eu consegui os dados), o problema surge quando eu quero mostrar esses dados json em meu widget de coluna **`(Column : [Text (), ...])`** Estou trabalhando com **null safety** (talvez isso tenha a ver com o problema, mas não tenho certeza, pois nas versões anteriores eu não tinha esse problema)

Este é o json que recebo:

```
[
    {
        "idCliente": "1",
        "ci": "1234567",
        "nombre": "jUAN",
        "apPaterno": "Perez",
        "apMaterno": "Fernandez",
        "correo": "juan123@gmail.com",
        "telefono": "7654321",
        "idUserss": "juan123",
        "imagenNueva": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "imagenAnterior": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "nombreImagenNueva": "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/vector-el-icono-del-avatar-del-usuario-para-el-sitio-web-o-el-m%C3%B3vil-45837377.jpg",
        "directorio": "imagenes"
    }
]
```

Este é o método responsável por me trazer o json:

```
Future<Perfil> listar() async {
  var url = 'https://midominio.com/data';
  var urlfull = Uri.parse(url);
  var response = await http.get(urlfull);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = response.body;
    var decoded = json.decode(result);
    print(decoded);
    var retornar = Perfil.fromJson(decoded);
    return retornar;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}
```

Esta é minha classe modelo para o json:

```
class Perfil {
  String idCliente;
  String ci;
  String nombre;
  String apPaterno;
  String apMaterno;
  String correo;
  String telefono;
  String idUserss;
  String imagenNueva;
  String imagenAnterior;
  String nombreImagenNueva;
  String directorio;

  Perfil({
    required this.idCliente,
    required this.ci,
    required this.nombre,
    required this.apPaterno,
    required this.apMaterno,
    required this.correo,
    required this.telefono,
    required this.idUserss,
    required this.imagenNueva,
    required this.imagenAnterior,
    required this.nombreImagenNueva,
    required this.directorio,
  });

  factory Perfil.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Perfil(
        idCliente: json["idCliente"] ?? json["idCliente"],
        ci: json["ci"] ?? json["ci"],
        nombre: json["nombre"] ?? json["nombre"],
        apPaterno: json["apPaterno"] ?? json["apPaterno"],
        apMaterno: json["apMaterno"] ?? json["apMaterno"],
        correo: json["correo"] ?? json["correo"],
        telefono: json["telefono"] ?? json["telefono"],
        idUserss: json["idUserss"] ?? json["idUserss"],
        imagenNueva: json["imagenNueva"] ?? json["imagenNueva"],
        imagenAnterior: json["imagenAnterior"] ?? json["imagenAnterior"],
        nombreImagenNueva:
            json["nombreImagenNueva"] ?? json["nombreImagenNueva"],
        directorio: json["directorio"] ?? json["directorio"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "idCliente": idCliente,
        "ci": ci,
        "nombre": nombre,
        "apPaterno": apPaterno,
        "apMaterno": apMaterno,
        "correo": correo,
        "telefono": telefono,
        "idUserss": idUserss,
        "imagenNueva": imagenNueva,
        "imagenAnterior": imagenAnterior,
        "nombreImagenNueva": nombreImagenNueva,
        "directorio": directorio,
      };
}
```

E esta é a minha **class** onde eu mostro os dados da API nos widgets mas ela me diz que o instantâneo está sem dados, ou seja, é como se não estivesse trazendo nada no json mas na verdade se eu obtiver os dados mas ele traz não o visualize.

```
class UserPerfil extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _UserPerfilState();
}

class _UserPerfilState extends State<UserPerfil> {
  Future<Perfil>? listaPerfil;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listaPerfil = listar();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Mi Perfil"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CurvaSesion(mcolor: Constants.global!),
          child: FutureBuilder<Perfil>(
              future: listaPerfil,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data!.nombre),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.apPaterno),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.apMaterno),
                        Text(snapshot.data!.correo),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                        child: Text(
                            "NO SE HA CARGADO LOS DATOS: ${snapshot.hasError}"));
                  }
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                          Theme.of(context).buttonColor),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Por favor, se alguém pudesse me ajudar eu agradeceria, estou seriamente pensando em voltar para uma versão mais antiga, pois até agora não fui capaz de resolver isso (suspeitando que talvez a null safety seja a culpada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não nos disse ao certo qual o teu problema, mas analisando teu JSON, possivelmente é um problema com a forma com o qual você o trata, mude o seguinte bloco para:

```
Future<Perfil> listar() async {
  var url = 'https://midominio.com/data';
  var urlfull = Uri.parse(url);
  var response = await http.get(urlfull);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = response.body;
    var decoded = json.decode(result);
    print(decoded);
    var retornar = Perfil.fromJson(decoded[0]);
    return retornar;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}
```

### Explicação

O problema que está enfrentando é por conta do JSON retornado da sua API.
Você está retornando um array de objetos, que por sua vez ao ser feito o "decode" no flutter, está lhe retornando uma `List<dynamic>`.

O problema é fácilmente resolvido pegando o primeiro item da lista para transformá-lo em um objeto *Perfil*.

```
var retornar = Perfil.fromJson(decoded[0]);
```